# New installation Zimbra mails end up in Spam folder of Gmail and Yahoo

Tags: email, email-server, zimbra

I have setup a new Zimbra Open Source installation. This is a new email server and the IP of this server is not Black listed in most prominent Block Lists. But what ever I have tried the emails still end up in the Spam folder. The headers which I received in my gmail account is as given is as below

http://pastie.org/1308039

Comment: Full marks for providing relevant information in the question! Its the nature of spam detection that most companies are cagey about publishing information about how they detect spam - and in the case of bayesian filtering they may not even know! Have you tried the Gmail bulk sender guidelines? https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=17205

Comment: Yup tried that. But no hope.

Comment: how do you manage the MX registration. Are you using a fqdn (best practice) or the ip for the MX tag (not recommended).
Do you have the PTR correctly declared on your public ip? Is a new domain or you was migrate from another server. Some times change the MX direction reduce the "reputation" of your domain. Check the Gmail bulk sender guidelines too.

Answer (score 0):

You know getting mail to Yahoo, Hotmail and Gmail can be a real hassle. There are lots of people using relays as smtp2go or amazon for getting their mail through. One catch that you maybe missed (although I didn't see it in the headers) could be disabling the Origin-IP header which exposes the ip address of the person composing the e-mail and could be used as an originating ip address. You can disable it by:

```
zmprov mcf zimbraSmtpSendAddOriginatingIP FALSE
```

If you give up and want to try an extra relay, you can find more on that in this thread:

[Using Amazon SES to send mails to specific domains in Zimbra](https://serverfault.com/questions/779234/using-amazon-ses-to-send-mails-to-specific-domains-in-zimbra)